# How do I share data between several threads when I need it mutable only rarely?

Tags: rust

I have some data of type `T` which implements neither `Copy` nor `Clone`.

1. If I want to share my data between several threads immutably, I'll use `Arc<T>`.
2. If I want to share it mutably, I'll use `Arc<Mutex<T>>`.

What if I want to share it first mutably, and then immutably in a loop? So:

- I cannot use either `Arc<T>` or `Arc<Mutex<Arc<T>>>` because I will not be able to mutate the data in the "mutable" threads.
- I can use `Arc<Mutex<T>>`, but then I have to `lock()` it in each of the "immutable" threads to reach `T`, losing parallelism.
- I cannot copy data after mutation is complete, because it is expensive (or there is no way to implement `Clone`).

What is the right effective solution then?

Comment: Do you know of a solution to this in any other language? That might give us somewhere to start from. My general solution would be "break it into smaller pieces". Maybe you can have finer-grained locking or do the problem in many independent pieces each atomically but many concurrently.

Comment: Many c-like languages have standalone mutexes which are separated from data. So I'd just use a lock while accessing my state in "mutable" threads, and not use it in "immutable" ones. I know exactly that there would be no data races (according to program structure), but I don't know how to prove it for rust compiler.

Comment: What about a [RWLock](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html)? Allows for multiple concurrent readers or one writer.

Comment: That is quite the thing! Thank you very much!

Comment: can't you simply move it out of the `Arc<Mutex<T>>` into an `Arc<T>` afterwards? or do you have to modify it again later?

Comment: Yes, I have to repeat these two steps in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`std::sync::RwLock`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) is what I am looking for, thanks @Shepmaster!

Answer (score 0):

For some use-cases (cache for example), `Arc<Mutex<Arc<T>>>` is an interesting solution.

The main difference with `RwLock`: you can get the value and use it without keeping the read lock.

```
fn get<T>(mutex: &Arc<Mutex<Arc<T>>>) -> Arc<T> {
    mutex.lock().unwrap().clone()
}
```

Full example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a2db2cd8aebf6a246486679f841827a