# Concurrent finder function

Tags: rust, concurrent-programming

I am trying to write a concurrent finder function for vectors, that under the hood splits the `Vec` into parts and uses a thread for each part. Every thread  iterates over its own piece of the array and if it finds element it should stop the main function. For a vector `0..n` and 4 threads:

```
thread1: iterate over 0..(n/4)
thread2: iterate over n/4..(n/2)
thread3: iterate over n/2..(n/2 +(n/4))
thread3: iterate over (n/2 +(n/4))..n
```

This is my implementation. It works, but is not what I want:

```
use std::thread;

fn finder(ref arr:&Vec<i32>, start:i32, end:i32, find:i32) {
    // for simplification
    for c in start..end {
        if c == find {
            println!("Boom!");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
   let array_init:Vec<i32> = (1..10_000_001).collect();
   let part = 2500000;
   let f_number = 9875640;

   let handles: Vec<_> = (1..4).map(|num| {
        let array = array_init.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            finder(&array, (num * part), ((num + 1) * part), f_number);
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

This version is slower than the non-concurrent finder function. The problem is this line: `let array = array_init.clone();` Every thread makes a copy of the initial array. For massive vectors, this operation is expensive.

I have two questions:

1. What is the Rust way to solve this problem, using only one vector without copies?
2. The initial array is an immutable resource, why can't I share it between threads like this:

   ```
      let array_init:Vec<i32> = (1..10_000_001).collect();
      let part = 2500000;
      let f_number = 9875640;

      let handles: Vec<_> = (1..4).map(|num| {

           thread::spawn(move || {
               finder(&array_init, (num * part), ((num + 1) * part), f_number);
           })
       }).collect();

       for h in handles {
           h.join().unwrap();
       }
   ```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216262/how-to-do-data-parallel-image-processing or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599334/how-do-i-run-parallel-threads-of-computation-on-a-partitioned-array perhaps?

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477757/how-do-you-send-slices-of-a-vec-to-a-task-in-rust or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224151/sharing-data-between-several-threads-arc-mutex-combination or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862646/reading-immutable-value-inside-spawned-thread ?

Comment: @Shepmaster thx, you are right, i ll delete my question

Comment: no need to delete, just mark it as a duplicate of what was most useful.